# Could you simplify the highlighted part of this passage?

Tags: word-meaning

> Every follower of Bahá’u’lláh knows well that the purpose of His Revelation is to **bring into**  **being a new creation** .  **No sooner had** “the First Call gone forth from His lips than the whole creation was revolutionized, and all that are in the heavens and all that are on earth were stirred to the depths.”  The individual, the institutions, and the community—the three protagonists in the Divine Plan—are being shaped under the direct influence of His Revelation, and a new conception of each, appropriate for **a humanity that has come of age** , is emerging.  The relationships that bind them, too, are undergoing a profound transformation, bringing into the realm of existence civilization-building powers which can only be released through conformity with His decree.  At a fundamental level these relationships are characterized by cooperation and reciprocity, manifestations of the interconnectedness that governs the universe.  So it is that the individual, with no regard for “personal benefits and selfish advantages,” comes to see him- or herself as “one of the servants of God, the All-Possessing,” whose only desire is to carry out His laws.

1. I need a simpler equivalent to the expression **bring into** and **being a new creation** . Does the word "creation" mean " a new society or a new group of people" ?
2. ** a humanity that has come if age** , could you write it in simple English, please?

Answer (score 2):

1. In a religious context, "creation" means the whole universe -- "all that are in the heavens and all that are on earth." "All creation" is a common phrase that uses this meaning. "Bring into being" means to create something. That sentence is a fancy, dramatic way of saying "...the purpose of His Revelation is to create a new world."
2. "Coming of age" means growing up -- moving from childhood to adulthood. Here, it refers to a change from a primitive state of selfishness to an enlightened state of "cooperation and reciprocity." A simpler version would be: "...appropriate for a mature humanity."

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to religious language this pregnant with meaning, one cannot reword it without changing its meaning, its effect on people.

Here are some simpler suggestions, though:

bring into being a new creation -> create anew

a humanity that has come of age -> a mature humanity